# PHP Datatables, Invalid JSON

Tags: php, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have a table based on a SQL query that I'm running through PHP that I would like to apply Datatables to for presentation and sorting purposes.  However, when I run the page in the browser, I receive an error that indicates that I have an invalid JSON response.

Here is my code:

PHP script (with HTML):

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM SCHEMA.DETAIL_TABLE";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row_count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.3/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/detail_sorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.3/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="disposalDetailTable" class="display">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th>Ticket Number</th> 
                <th>Bay Number</th> 
                <th>Date Time</th> 
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Driver</th> 
                <th>Total</th> 
                <th>Unload Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
<?php
//This is the main detail data table.  We loop through the SELECT statement.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".($row[15])."</td>
            <td>".($row[1])."</td>
            <td>".($row[2])."</td>
            <td>".($row[5])."</td>
            <td>".($row[8])."</td>
            <td>".(round($row[12], 1))."</td>
            <td>".(round($row[13], 1))."</td>
        </tr>";
}
?>
    </tbody>
    </table> 

</body>
```

Here is my jQuery (filename = detail_sorter.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#disposalDetailTable').DataTable();
});
```

I feel like I'm trying to keep it too simple.  When use a static table the Datatables functionality works perfect.  However, when I add the PHP dynamically I get the error that I mentioned.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i don't see any json in your code

Comment: PHP is probably not outputting the data you think it is. Also, use mysqli_ or PDO, mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Create a minimal, complete, verifiable example. First step. Flatten the HTML. Take PHP out of the equation. Does your javascript work? If so, post a question specific to outputting from PHP directly like the HTML that you tested. If not, the question has nothing to do with PHP and it's more along the lines of "Why isn't this Datatable working?"

Comment: Your code is fine except the SQL: `SELECT *  FROM SCHEMA.DETAIL_TABLE` what on earth? :) What do you expect `SCHEMA` to do here?  I believe you mean  `SELECT *  FROM DETAIL_TABLE` ...